# How I know my device screen ratio

Tags: screen, screen-resolution

I have a game where the monsters list appear in 4 columns on my devices, But I have seen videos on youtube where display 5 columns.

Even one of my very old device 1280x720 screen resolution also display 5 columns

But my newer devices doesnt.

- One is Galaxy Tab S 10'' 2560 x 1600 (WQXGA) ~288 ppi http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_gala...5_lte-6235.php
- The other is LG Flex 2 Curve 5.5" (1920 x 1080) with 403 ppi http://www.gsmarena.com/lg_g_flex2-6916.php

So what is the difference? I think maybe is something regarding the screen ratio. But not sure what or how I check so when I buy my next device work properly

[image]

Comment: Isn't the ratio just a simple calculation? e.g. 2560x1600 -> 16:10.

Comment: Problem is, the layout also has to do with the density setting of the device. That is something you can't figure out by just looking at the specs of a device.

Comment: @AndyYan So how I get that?

Comment: Check `/system/build.prop` and look for `ro.sf.lcd_density` - it controls the overall scale of UI. If you're rooted you can modify that value to your desire; it's also possible to modify it on a per-app basis, so that only this app gets scaled. I'll not go into details now, look it up first.

Answer (score 0):

To know your phone's aspect ratio and\or resolution there are many ways. One way is to go to this website and it'll immediately show you:
http://whatismyresolution.com/. If you'd like to know the ratio before buying any device you can simply ask about it. Most game developers intentionally develop games to adjust to any ratio the device is on, but some games aren't developed that way. This is most likely one of those games.. It really depends on your phone's screen size